# How to upgrade AG-GRID Version from Angularjs v1.5 ag-grid v18 to Angularjs v1.5 ag-grid v28

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

In this AngularJS v1.5, we are using AG-GRID v18. How Can add AG-GRID v28+. Because in v28+ we are having this blank and more filters options by default. So, please suggest your thoughts.

Version Details:

AngularJS v1.5.8
ag-grid v18.0.1

Comment: Is this different than [How to add an Blank filter option in my "Angularjs v1.5" code for the filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77145815/how-to-add-an-blank-filter-option-in-my-angularjs-v1-5-code-for-the-filter)?

Comment: Yes, Here, we are planning to upgrade the version. There we need to add Blank filters.

But if we can upgrade the ag-grid v28+ in angujar js v1.5 then it will become default filter. If not we need to plan for adding blank filter.